# How to move/redraw CGPathRef?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

I have an app where one view has something similiar to a MS Visio configuration. You can add different nodes (Circles, rendered from a UIImage), and then connect them with lines, to create something similar to a Tree Data representation. The adding part works fine.

```
-(void) drawLineToCache{

   // Circle *dad;
   // Circle *kid; 
   //      Circle is a wrapper class for the nodes.. dad and kid are   
   //      private instances declared earlier in this paint view

//associatedPaths is a NSMutableArray that contains Line objects, 
//       which is simply a wrapper class with a CGPathRef
    [dad.associatedPaths addObject:self.selectedLine]; 
    [kid.associatedPaths addObject:self.selectedLine]; 

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, dad.middlePoint.x, dad.middlePoint.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, kid.middlePoint.x, kid.middlePoint.y);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    CGContextAddPath(cacheContext, path);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(cacheContext,[UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextStrokePath(cacheContext);
    CGPathRelease(path);

    CGRect dirtyRect = CGRectMake(dad.middlePoint.x-10, dad.middlePoint.y-10, 500, 400);
    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:dirtyRect];

}
```

What I want to be able to do now, is move the circles around, and delete them. Since the circles are UIImageViews, move/delete them by simply updating the frame/removing it from the subview.

And then in order to update it I tried:

```
//Ideally this should be implemented in touchesMoved, but I 
//thought it might be too much for the renderer.. 
// movingCircle is simply a reference to which circle needs to be updated 
// (the above kid/dad). I have been able to debug it to the point that the 
// associatedPath arrays contains the correct lines.. 
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

    for (Line *line in movingCircle.associatedPaths) {
        CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutableCopy(line.path);
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, line.parentNode.middlePoint.x, line.parentNode.middlePoint.y);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, line.childNode.middlePoint.x, line.childNode.middlePoint.y);
        CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
        CGContextAddPath(cacheContext, path);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(cacheContext,[UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
        CGContextStrokePath(cacheContext);
        CGPathRelease(path);


    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    movingCircle = nil;
}
```

But it doesnt work... I'm aware that this would only draw a new line (and not delete the old one), but won't even do that much.. I also have zero idea how to delete the old one...

My question is: How to do the same with the lines? I can gladly store every path in a array for each circle, but even so, after accessing the paths, how do I update them?? Do I need to draw a new one, and somehow delete the old? Or can I simply change one of the end points of the line?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store them in a mutable array and simply replace any line that needs to be changed. You could think about storing and applying a transform to each but that will be more complex and likely not result in such a crisp result. Once you have updated the paths in the array you simply redraw the affected area of the screen.

You might also want to use bezier paths instead of CG paths (brighter level API more comparable to the image views you're using).

Comment: Can you maybe show me some example code? I tried doing that and wasnt very succesful

Comment: And what would be the advantages of UIBezierPath? I looked into the class and thought it would be too complicated for what I'm doing, but I'm very new to CG..

Comment: It would mean you wouldn't need to interact with the CG context, just set the fill colour with UIColor and then stroke / fill the bezier.

Comment: Ok, if you have `movingCircle.associatedPaths`, make it an array of bezier paths. Once you've done that you can call `removeAllPoints` on the bezier and replace with the point of the 2 circles. You should also be able to do it in touches moved so long as you set the area of screen that needs to be drawn (and respect that in your `drawRect:` implementation).

Comment: Ok, and then at the moment of drawing, should I draw the BezierPath or the CGPathRef? And how do I draw a UIBezierPath?

Comment: just call `stroke` on the bezier and it will draw into the current context. Call `setStroke` on a `UIColor` first.

Comment: If I do that I get an **CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update**..
I hadcreated my own ContextRef following [this](http://www.effectiveui.com/blog/2011/12/02/how-to-build-a-simple-painting-app-for-ios/) demo to optimize the renderer.. but perhaps its not the best idea..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40362/discussion-between-wain-and-cutetare)